# Smart Contract Transfer Event Log Data & transfer _value [Rust]

Tags: transactions, tokens, events, logs, rust

I'd like to have a better understanding of events and logs data, more specifically when it comes to interacting with ERC20 tokens smart contracts and their `Transfer` events.

I'm looking for a way to extract the transfer value/amount from the returned (transaction) Log struct as described in the [rust-web3 documentation](https://tomusdrw.github.io/rust-web3/web3/types/struct.Log.html).

I understand that from the event log, the `topics` field has 3 values:

- `topics[0]` is the keccak-256 of the
  `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` canonical signature.
- `topics[1]` is the value of the _from address.
- `topics[2]` is the value of the _to address.

However, I cannot seem to find the ERC20 token transaction value in the returned `Log` struct or the `log` or `input` field as described in this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26640/find-topic0-topic1-topic2) and this [one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/understanding-logs-and-log-blooms).

I suspect I can extract the transfer amount in an ERC20 token transaction from the `data` field in the events log but I haven’t figured how to do that yet. data is of type Bytes, i.e. a Vec`<u8>`, a vector of 32 `u8`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question:

The `data` field from the returned `Log` struct contains indeed the transferred token amount value:

The `Bytes`' vector needs to be converted into a hexadecimal figure (by looping through the vector and converting its value at each index into a hex and concatenating all the converted values together) to look like the log's `data` shown  [in the first linked thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/understanding-logs-and-log-blooms).

eg:

`data: Bytes([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 141, 126, 164, 198, 128, 0])`

is equivalent to:

`data: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000`

which converted back to a single decimal is:

`1000000000000000000` = `10^(18)` => `1` ERC20 transferred token